# Refactoring to Gulp 4

Tags: javascript, gulp

I know there's lots of post about this but I can't find a solution.

This is my gulpfile that I tried to refactor but without success so trying here to get some answers. Tried everything I found about Gulp 3 -> Gulp 4 but nothing works. Maybe someone had a similar setup that needed conversion?

It was a long time ago since I touched this code and I feel a bit lost with Gulp right now.

````
  return gulp.src('app/src/files/**/*.pdf')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + '/files'))
});

gulp.icons ({
    return gulp.src('app/src/icons/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite(config))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});


gulp.css({
    const processors = [
        atImport,
        cssnext,
        mqpacker,
        clearfix,
        cssnano
    ];
    return gulp.src('app/src/css/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

gulp.nunjucks({
    return gulp.src('app/pages/*.njk')
    // Adding data to Nunjucks
        .pipe(data(function () {
            return require('./data.json')
        }))
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: ['app/pages/', 'app/templates/'] // String or Array
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

gulp.browser-sync({
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: dist
        }
    });
});

gulp.scripts({
    return gulp.src('app/src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.images({
    return gulp.src('app/src/img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('${dist}/img'))
});

gulp.watch({
    gulp.watch('app/templates/**/*.+(njk)', ['nunjucks', reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.+(njk)', ['nunjucks', reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/src/**/*.css', ['css', reload]);
    gulp.watch(['app/src/js/**/*.js', 'main.js'], ['scripts', reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/src/img/**/*', ['images', reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/src/icons/**/*', ['icons', reload]);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('nunjucks', 'css', 'files', 'scripts', 'icons', 'images', 'watch', 'browser-sync'));
gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('nunjucks', 'files', 'css', 'scripts', 'icons', 'images'));```
````

Answer (score 0):

This form is wrong:

```
gulp.icons ({
    return gulp.src('app/src/icons/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite(config))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});
```

change **all** to :

```
gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/src/icons/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite(config))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});
```

And all your `watch` statements are wrong, change all of them to this form:

`gulp.watch('app/templates/**/*.+(njk)', gulp.series('nunjucks', reload));`

You don't show the `reload` function so I assume it is a function and not in the `gulp.task('reload')` form??

I would also change this:

`gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('nunjucks', 'css', 'files', 'scripts', 'icons', 'images', 'watch', 'browser-sync'));`

since you call `browser-sync` last, `gulp.series` would be better so that the other tasks have completed on first run and their changes will be shown in the browser on first run:

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('nunjucks', 'css', 'files', 'scripts', 'icons', 'images', 'watch', 'browser-sync'));`

Comment: Thank's for this! I got it to build now. The only thing I don't get to work is the 'watch' task:


```gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('app/templates/**/*.+(njk)', gulp.series('nunjucks', reload));
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.+(njk)', gulp.series('nunjucks', reload));
    gulp.watch('app/src/**/*.css', gulp.series('css', reload));
    gulp.watch(['app/src/js/**/*.js', 'main.js'], gulp.series('scripts', reload));
    gulp.watch('app/src/img/**/*', gulp.series('images', reload));
    gulp.watch('app/src/icons/**/*', gulp.series('icons', reload));
});```